# android.net.SntpClient is missing from Android SDK

Tags: java, android, class, sdk, compilation

I am trying to get time from an Internet Time Server. And I found that android.net.SntpClient is a good solution that I could use.

But my Android SDK (Android API 19) does not contain that class. I downloaded the "Sources for Android SDK" via SDK Manager and the source code contains the SntpClient.java (source file for class android.net.SntpClient)

Please view the images links I uploaded. (sorry, I dont have enough reputation for images right here)

The android SDK:
https://scontent-a-sea.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/1888504_897281990284152_2310291065247680835_n.jpg?oh=989c5f49848a8914d77bb0d4aac8897d&oe=54F8E9D6

The sources:
https://scontent-a-sea.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/10659310_897281993617485_1823842706987095742_n.jpg?oh=27ee6a075967731dc7265352c22002cd&oe=54DCBB73

Could anyone tell me why this file is not compiled? If I want to use this class, I have to explain to my boss why android SDK doesn't contain it.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Google has chosen not to make all public classes available as part of the SDK. Visibility is controlled by the @hide comment tag [as described here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/net/SntpClient.java/?v=source).

I'm not sure why they chose to hide SntpClient particularly, but provided you respect the terms of the Apache license you can copy the source into your application without much modification.